# Windows bootloader deleted

Tags: windows-10, bootloader, easybcd

My grub2 menu was missing after I reinstall windows 10. However i managed to get it back from windows by using *easybcd*. But somehow my windows bootloader has been deleted from easybcd menu and now i cannot boot windows. But I still have grub2 menu. How can I fix this from ubuntu, since I can't change this from windows without boot.

Comment: UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: @Celtic is right to ask - if legacy, you might be able to configure grub to boot the Windows partition.

Comment: @CelticWarrior is there any way to check it without booting to windows?